# SSL Multidomain for Magento 2 on Google Cloud

Tags: magento-2.1, ssl, multidomain

I have the follow situation:

My Magento 2 installation has 4 stores and it is hosted in google cloud compute engine with the main domain as an IP address like 35.999.444.22. I have a SSL certificate for one of my stores domain. But it is not working. Do I have to get another SSL certificate for the main address: 35.999.444.22?

This is how I configure my nginx server replacing with my certificates. When I add this code I can't run nginx on docker anymore.

```
server {
listen 443;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl_bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/meusite.key;

ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;

ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;

server_name meusite.com.br;
}
```

Comment: Please could you expand on "it's not working".

Comment: I configure my nginx server but I can't run my nginx container when I run docker-compose up -d. When I remove the ssl configuration it works normally.

Comment: Following comodo tutorial I add this code to my server with certificates name:


server {
listen 443;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl_bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/meusite.key;

ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;

ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;

server_name meusite.com.br;
}